# Flicker on bars

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the XAML code below but it's not smooth and creates flicker once in a while. How can i improve this in XAML? I have tried multiple solutions but it always seem to create flicker multiple times within a minute. Is this because of the frame rate of my monitor and the source code or? Please help. If you have examples on getting this smooth i would appreciate it.

```
<Window x:Class="BarsTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BarsTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black">
            <Rectangle Height="1080" Width="160" Fill="White">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform0" X="-160" Y="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Height="1080" Width="160" Fill="White">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform1" X="160" Y="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Height="1080" Width="160" Fill="White">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform2" X="480" Y="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Height="1080" Width="160" Fill="White">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform3" X="800" Y="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Height="1080" Width="160" Fill="White">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform4" X="1120" Y="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Height="1080" Width="160" Fill="White">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform5" X="1440" Y="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Height="1080" Width="160" Fill="White">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform6" X="1760" Y="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>

            <StackPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="myBeginStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard DesiredFrameRate="60">
                            <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" From="-160" To="160" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" From="0" To="320" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" From="160" To="480" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" From="320" To="640" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" From="480" To="800" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" From="640" To="960" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" From="800" To="1120" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </StackPanel.Triggers>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Br
ARUS

Comment: I'm not facing any issues with your code. May be it is your hardware.

Comment: Thanks RajN. It doesnt happen all the time but one in a while just for a short period of time. Is there anyway i can check my HW to make sure it fits to the SW i create?

Comment: Check your PC resource, it should be free enough for Storyboard animation, i am unable to found problem running smooth

Comment: But don't any of you see small flicker once in a while if you focus on the signal?

Comment: I think this might also be called stutter